# Не копируются файлы через ifneq

Tags: android, bash, shell, makefile

Всем привет!
Никак при сборке android не могу заставить копировать нужное.

В папке vendor/nitrogen/prebuilt/common/bootanimation/geehrc.zip
А $(TARGET_DEVICE) выводит geehrc.

Вот кусок кода, но он не работает...

```
# Bootanimation (add if it exists)
ifneq ("$(wildcard vendor/nitrogen/prebuilt/common/bootanimation/$(TARGET_DEVICE).zip)","")
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    vendor/nitrogen/prebuilt/common/bootanimation/$(TARGET_DEVICE).zip:system/media/bootanimation.zip
endif
```

Как исправить?
А не может быть такого что путь слишком длинный?

Comment: 1. в приведённом вами фрагменте нет ничего по поводу копирования. 2. пожалуйста, сформулируйте проблему и сопроводите её [кратким, завершенным и достоверным примером](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: есть, а что продакт копи файлс не копирует ничего?

Comment: PRODUCT_COPY_FILES — это просто имя переменной.